# Do not start openssh server on startup

Tags: openssh

I do not want to start the openssh server on startup, but just by command if I need to.

By default, openssh always starts with booting, I removed in file `/etc/init/ssh.conf` the following line:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
```

but it still starts every time with booting. What do I need to do? Of course, I could setup a startup script to shut it off, but it would be much better simply disable starting it..

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: The link to the other question was correct, in short, the answer is `systemctl disable ssh`